# How to call php explode function in html

Tags: php, html

```
<?php 
 function rand_word(){
 $lines = file("words.txt") ;
  $random_index = rand(0,count($lines)-1);
  $random_line = $lines[$random_index];
  $definition = explode("\t", $random_line)
 }
?>
<html>
  words: 
  part:
  definition:
</html>
```

Two questions: how do i call the exploded lines in html, i've tried the code below but none of them work.
`<?=$definition[0]?>
<?php rand_word(); ?>
<?php echo rand_word(); ?>
<?php echo defintion[0]; ?>`

A line in the file for example:
**rescind   verb    to take away or remove**

Comment: try with CSS tag `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: `rand_word()` is missing `return` and `<?=` does not look like a proper php processing instruction.

Comment: I read that in a book actually, but the other ones are right syntax but don't work

Comment: @digijay `<?=` is a shorthand for `<?php` and it is a valid PHP open tag (most of the time)

Comment: Yes, if you define `short_open_tag=On` in your php.ini

Comment: Syntax errors in your PHP script.

Comment: No, `<?=` is a shorthand for `<?php echo`, and it does not depend on `short_open_tag=On` any more since PHP 5.4, but is always available.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't returned any value from function you can simply print values direct from your function example:

```
<?php 
 function rand_word(){
 $lines = file("words.txt") ;
  $random_index = rand(0,count($lines)-1);
  $random_line = $lines[$random_index];
  $definition = explode("\t", $random_line);
  echo defintion[0];
 }

 rand_word();
?>
```

or you can return values from function to use outside...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access local variable outside function but you can return from function for more info visit https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

```
    <?php 
     function rand_word(){
        $lines = file("words.txt") ;
        $random_index = rand(0,count($lines)-1);
        $random_line = $lines[$random_index];
        return explode("\t", $random_line);
     }
    ?>

   ...

    <?php echo reset(rand_word()); ?>
```

Comment: why reset the function?

Comment: reset() rewinds array's internal pointer to the first element and returns the value of the first array element. here rand_word() returns array